# Adding integers of array upto some number (java)

Tags: java

I have a java question.

I have two `int[]` arrays: `cdn` and `cmn`.
`cdn` is `{1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}` 
`cmn` is `{8,8,16}`
I need a program that adds the consecutive integers of `cdn[]` upto `cmn[init]` and returns the number of integers used in the addition. Then it continues adding from the next integer of `cdn[]` upto `cmn[init+1]` and return the number of integers. For the arrays above this is done 3 times: the first time the return value is 7, the second time it is 7, and the third time it is 16. The number of integers can be collected in and `int[]` which is `{7,7,16}`. The code I have is:

```java
int numofints = 0;
int init = 0;
int plus = 0;
while(init < m2){
 for(int j = 0; j < cdn.length; j++){
    plus += cdn[j];
    numofints++;
  if(plus == cmn[init]){
   init++;
  }
 }
}
System.out.print(numofints);
```

in which `m2` is the size of `cmn`, which is 3 in this case. Note that my program starts to loop from the beginning of `cdn` over and over again, because `j = 0`. I want it to start where it ended the previous time!
I hope you have a solution for me.

Bjorn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just pull `j` out of the outer loop, and use a `while`, instead of `for`, for the inner loop

and you also need to put `plus = 0` into the loop

```
public class T {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] cdn = {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    int[] cmn = {8,8,16};

    int numofints = 0;
    int init = 0;
    int m2 = 3;

    int j = 0;
    while(init < m2){
     int plus = 0;
     while(j < cdn.length){
        plus += cdn[j];
        j++;
        numofints++;
        if(plus == cmn[init]){
          init++;
          System.out.println(j);
          break;
        } 
      }
    if (j == cdn.length) break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This piece of code is causing the compiler to get stuck. It looks right though. Do you know why?

Comment: you mean "compiler" get stuck or the execution never terminates?

Comment: It just stops doing anything (it is not an infinite loop).

Comment: what stops doing anything? compilation (`javac`) or execution?

Comment: The cursor is flickering during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Shoudln't `if(plus == cmn[init]){` be `if(plus >= cmn[init])`?  If you change cdn at all and "plus" happens to go over "cmn[init]", your code is going to break.